# best way to deploy jetty application--too many options?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I need to deploy a production version of a web application.  So far, I've been testing it with `mvn jetty:run`.  I've used actual jetty installations before, but they seem only necessary when you want to serve multiple wars on the same web server.  In some ways this is the most staightforward however (`mvn package` and copy it over).

My other options are to create a runnable jar (`mvn assembly:single`) that starts a server, but I need to tweak the configuration so that the static content `src/main/webapp` is served and the `web.xml` can be found.

I've also read about a "runnable war".  This might avoid the `src/main/webapp` problem since these files are already laid out in the warfile.  I don't know how to go about doing this, however.

I could also stick with `mvn jetty:run`, but this doesn't seem like the best option because then the production deployment is tied to code instead of being a standalone jar.

Any opinions on the best way or pros and cons of these different approaches?  Am I missing some options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jetty-console-maven-plugin](http://simplericity.com/2009/11/10/1257880778509.html) from simplericity is simple to use and works great.  When you run `mvn package` you get two wars--one that is executable.  `java -jar mywar.war --help` gives usage, which allows a bit of configuration (port, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with maven, but this is how we approach deployment using embedded Jetty:

We create a single-file JAR with the embedding jetty app and the necessary lib jars packed.

We deploy the static content in a WAR file (which you can package into the JAR as well). Everything is generated by an ANT file that:

1) Build the static files WAR (this also creates the web.xml)
2) Copies the WAR into the application resources
3) Compiles an executable JAR

To get the embedded Jetty to "find and serve" your static files, add the war with a WebAppContext to the Jetty handlers:

```
Server jetty = new Server(port);
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
WebAppContext staticContentAsWar = new WebAppContext();
staticContentAsWar.setContextPath("/static/");
staticContentAsWar.setWar(resource_Path_to_WAR);
handlers.addHandler(set);
jetty.setHandlers(handlers);
jetty.start();
```

HTH